# Wrapping a range of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

How would I select a rolling/wrapping* set of rows from a table?

I am trying to select a number of records (per type, 2 or 3) for each day, wrapping when I 'run out'.
Eg.

```
2018-03-15: YyBiz, ZzCo, AaPlace  
2018-03-16: BbLocation, CcStreet, DdInc
```

These are rendered within a SSRS report for Dynamics CRM, so I can do light post-query operations.

Currently I get to:

```
2018-03-15: YyBiz, ZzCo  
2018-03-16: AaPlace, BbLocation, CcStreet
```

First, getting a number for each record with:

```
SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY name) as RN
FROM table
```

Within SSRS, I then adjust RN to reflect the number of each type I need:

```
OnPageNum = FLOOR((RN+num_of_type-1)/num_of_type)-1
--Shift RN to be 0-indexed.
```

Resulting in `AaPlace, BbLocation` and `CcStreet` having a PageNum of 0, `DdInc` of 1, ... `YyBiz` and `ZzCo` of 8.

Then using an SSRS Table/Matrix linked to the dataset, I set the row filter to something like:

```
RowFilter = MOD(DateNum, NumPages(type)) == OnPageNum
```

Where DateNum is essentially days since epoch, and each page has a separate table and day passed in.

At this point, it is showing only N records of `type` per page, but if the total number of records of a type isn't a multiple of the number of records per page of that type, there will pages with less records than required.

Is there an easier way to approach this/what's the next step?

*Wrapping such as [Wraparound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wraparound_(video_games)) found in videogames, seamless resetting to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this effect, I found that offsetting the `RowNumber` by `-DateNum*num_of_type` (negative for positive ordering), then modulo `COUNT(type)` would provide the correct "wrap around" effect.

In order to achieve the desired pagination, it then just had to be divided by `num_of_type` and `floor`'d, as below:

```
RowFilter: FLOOR(((RN-DateNum*num_of_type) % count(type))/num_of_type) == 0
```